# Alter database table using hasColumns laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, schema

I have a table called `table1` and columns named `id`, `name`,`field1`, `field2`, `field3`.

And i want to check the columns are exist. If any one of the column does not exist, i want to add that columns to the table.

Eg: i have column names called `id`, `name`,`field1`, `field2`, `field3`. And i want to check is there any columns named `field3`, `field4`, `field5`. In this `field3` exists and other 2 are not. so i want to add that 2 columns in `table1` table. Is this possible using `hasColumns`?. Or suggest me other ways?

Comment: You should change DB structure. What you're trying to do is a really bad practice.

Comment: Did you mean there is no possible ways???

Comment: There are some ways, but you shouldn't use those. I'm pretty sure you can store `fieldX` data as JSON objects in DB without creating additional fields dynamically. Or find some other way to store the data.

Comment: Please read about hasMany relationship.

Comment: Can you show me any examples. I'am a newbie in laravel. And thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

Inside the controller's method write the following code:

```
    \Schema::table('table1', function (\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint $table) {
        if (!\Schema::hasColumns('table1', ['field4', 'field5'])) {
            $table->string('field4');
            $table->string('field5');
        }
    });
```

To know more visit [Table Migration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#tables)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually i want to done this all using controller.

Comment: I have edited answer. Inside your controller write the above code

Comment: What about if the code is like if (!\Schema::hasColumns('table1', ['field3','field4', 'field5'])) {

Comment: what will be the result?